# Azure sdk Iot Storage without account key same environment in agent

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have the code from below that works fine. My service and the storage are in the same environment in agent. Is there a way to write the credentials without having to provide a key, hence they are in the same environment in agent ?

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = 
new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, **accountKey**);

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
           .endpoint(endpoint)
           .credential(credential)
           .buildClient();
```

Comment: What do you mean with the same 'same environment in agent'? Are you running a web app or application on an azure VM that connects to the azure storage account?

Comment: The app and the storage are located on the same environment. The app is running inside Kubernetes. The storage is a dedicated one.

Comment: You can try using the overload with the `TokenCredential` to build your client using the `ManagedIdentityCredential` class. Then create a managed identity for your Kubernetes and assign it RBAC permission on the Storage Account resource. I have never tried it on a Kubernetes service so I'm unsure if that's all it takes.

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example ? I am still a little confused.

Comment: The following docs explains it well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-managed-identity and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#authenticate-in-azure-with-managed-identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to write the credentials without having to provide a key?

To avoid key credential, I agree with @NotFound that you can use **`Tokencredential`** with the [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-java-stable) method.

You need to assign RBAC roles to your storage account for accessing blob storage through identity, The roles are:-

- Storage-blob-data-contributor(or)
- Storage-blob-data-owner

*Go to portal -> storage accounts -> Access Control (IAM) ->Add -> Add role assignments -> storage-blob-contributor or storage-blob-owner role to the storage account.*

**Portal:**

[image]

I tried with sample code to upload a file from the local path to azure blob storage using identity it uploaded successfully.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.*;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.identity.*;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();
       BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .endpoint("https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/")
            .credential(credential)
            .buildClient();
            String  containerName = "test";
        BlobContainerClient  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        String  localPath = "<your local path >";
        BlobClient  blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("file.json");
        System.out.println("\nUploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t" + blobClient.getBlobUrl());
        blobClient.uploadFromFile(localPath);  
        System.out.println("Uploaded!!!");  
    }
}
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]